# Which package.json events does Azure Webapp call on deploy?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, package.json

It seems like Azure is calling 'preinstall', 'install' & 'postinstall'.
But, 'prepublish' and 'publish' are not called.

Is there a list of all the package.json events Azure Webapp is calling on deploy and when are they called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not call directly any specific package.json events. Instead, it calls `install --production`. So whatever set of scripts end up getting called by this command is what will get called.

See what the deployment script looks like here: 
https://gist.github.com/davidebbo/5357141#file-node-deploy-cmd-L103

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 'prepublish' to run automation ('gulp') before the publish.
I think that you can use 'publish' or 'postpublish' as well'

But it is happening every npm install not only on deploy